# How to pair with a bluetooth headset?

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have a MacBook Pro and use an Apple Magic Mouse. I want to pair a wireless headset but have not been able, I cannot even see where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System Preferences > Bluetooth` and make sure bluetooth is on (select `Turn Bluetooth On` if it isn't). Also make sure your headset is turned on. Wait for your headset to appear on the list on the right, select it and click `Pair`.

The actual pairing process might differ depending on the headset, e.g. whether it requires a PIN code or not. The possible PIN required should be found from the headset's user guide.