# How to return the device on MacBook Air on Bluetooth?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

I accidentally tap on forgot the device on MacBook Air and delete Beats solo3 from the Bluetooth device list? Any ideas how to return the device? Can you guys help me please, I try everything...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pair with a bluetooth headset?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173672/how-to-pair-with-a-bluetooth-headset)

Comment: Generally, to connect a Bluetooth device to anything else, you need to turn on its pairing mode. Then the device you're trying to connect it to will be able to find it. I did a quick google search ["how to turn on pairing mode Beats solo3"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfjdE.png). Here's the [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207108#pair).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to be more clear next time. We can't really figure out what you mean by 'I tried everything' ;)

### On your Mac :

1. Go to Apple () menu > System Preferences > Bluetooth
   [image]

### On your headphones :

1. Press the power button for 5 seconds
2. Wait for the led to flash
3. Go back to your Mac's bluetooth settings, at the bottom of the devices list you should now see a `Connect` button next to the headphones icon / name (as shown on the example below)

[image]

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207108